# Spark Cluster on EC2 - "ssh-ready" state pops up for password

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a Spark cluster on EC2 with the following command 
(I am referring [Apache documetnation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ec2-scripts.html#launching-a-cluster-in-a-vpc))

```
./spark-ec2 --key-pair=spark-cluster --identity-file=/Users/abc/spark-cluster.pem --slaves=3 --region=us-west-1 --zone=us-west-1c --vpc-id=vpc-2e44594 --subnet-id=subnet-18447841 --spark-version=1.6.1 launch spark-cluster
```

Once I fire above command master and slaves are getting created but once process reaches to 'SSH-ready' state process keeps on waiting for password

below is the Trace. I have referred apache official documentation and many other documents/videos none of the creations asked for the password. not sure  whether I am missing something, any pointer to this issue is much appreciated.

> Creating security group spark-cluster-master Creating security group
>   spark-cluster-slaves Searching for existing cluster spark-cluster in
>   region us-west-1... Spark AMI: ami-1a250d3e Launching instances...
>   Launched 3 slaves in us-west-1c, regid = r-32249df4 Launched master in
>   us-west-1c, regid = r-5r426bar Waiting for AWS to propagate instance
>   metadata...
>   **
>
> > Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state..........Password:
>
> **

Comment: Can you post the output of  `ssh -v -i /Users/abc/spark-cluster.pem root@<ip-of-a-slave>` ?

Comment: :ec2 1$ ssh -v -i /Users/abc/spark-cluster.pem root@10.80.121.200
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/abc/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.80.xx.xxx [xx.xx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.xx.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.80.xxx.xxx port 22: "Operation timed out"

Comment: Tried again and stuck at same point -below is the trace                    Launching instances...
Launched 1 slave in us-west-1c, regid =  r-5r426bar
Launched master in us-west-1c, regid = r-32249df4
Waiting for AWS to propagate instance metadata...
Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.........Password:

Comment: The output is not useful since the host is not accepting connection from your machine. What is the permission of /Users/abc/spark-cluster.pem? `ls -l /Users/abc/spark-cluster.pem`

Comment: it is 400       -r--------@

Comment: Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: 
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: Warning: Permanently added '' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Received disconnect from ::1: 2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from ::1

.Password:

Comment: Did you provide a passphrase when generating the cluster key (using ssh-keygen)?

Comment: No, I have not given any password while creating the key pair.

Comment: it is a problem with spark-ec2.py script. i have updated it and it started working. thank you @helloV for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the spark-ec2.py script to include the proxy and enabled the AWS Nat to allow the outbound calls